# Can't pass process carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I cannot pass process in Carrierwave for some reason. I made a form, and everytime I upload an image, the form doesn't go through. However, if I comment out `process`, the form goes through. Same goes with the version thumb. I do not know how to fix it.

**ImageUploader**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # process resize_to_fit: [200, 200]

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [200, 200]
  end

  def extension_whitelist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

**Form:**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Add new course ') %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Create courses') %>
<h1>New Course</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_for(@course, html: {multipart:true}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_course', object: @course %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', :required => true %>

  <%= f.label "Prerequisite" %>
  <%= f.text_field :prereq, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label "Description" %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control', :required => true %>


  <%= f.label "Coordinator" %>
  <%= f.text_field :coord, :value => @user, readonly: true, class: 'form-control' %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Location: "%>
    <% Location.all.each do |location|%>
    <%= check_box_tag "course[location_ids][]", location.id, false%>
    <%= location.loc_name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Category: " %>
    <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "course[category_ids][]", category.id%>
    <%= category.cat_name %>
    <% end %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.file_field :image %>
 </div>

  <%= f.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

**Model:**

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
    ....
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Basically, if I comment out `process` actions, the form will go through, but if I don't then it doesn't. Don't know the reason why.